# dropdown submenu in selection list

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

i have created a dropdown menu with provinces name and below each province its citesties are mentioned. I want these cities to appear in submenu on left side of province when it is clicked.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">


<select name="campus" id="campuslocation" class="browser-default" required="">
  <optgroup label="Eastern Cape">
    <option value="31">Umtata / Mthatha</option>
    <option value="32">Willowmore</option>
    <option value="33">Willowvale</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Free State">
    <option value="47">Koppies</option>
    <option value="48">Kroonstad</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

[image: as show in this pic Gauteng is province and it's cities are in side menu]

Answer (score 3):

`select` is not the right element for this task, [a `dropdown` is much better](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/dropdowns/#single-button) suited.

There is no default way to create submenus but it's easy enough to achieve.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dropdown-submenu a').on("click", function(e) {
    $(this).parents('ul').find('.dropdown-submenu ul').hide();
    $(this).next('ul').toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
.dropdown-submenu {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -1px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    All South Africa
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Eastern Cape</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Umtata / Mthatha</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Willowmore</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Willowvale</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Free State</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Koppies</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Kroonstad</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I am using select tag in form .... navigation bar or menu is not required. the main problem is how to show another list when click on an option in select list.

Comment: you can't do that with a select list, you need to use a different element

Answer (score 1):

Hope, this will help. We can able to use ,

instead of select.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            .dropdown-submenu {
                position: relative;
            }

            .dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
                top: 0;
                left: 100%;
                margin-top: -1px;
            }

            .dropdown {
                width: 100px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Select State
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                        <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">Eastern Cape <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Umtata / Mthatha</a></li>
                            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Willowmore</a></li>
                            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Willowvale</a></li>
                        </ul>

                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                        <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">Free State <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Umtata / Mthatha</a></li>
                            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Willowmore</a></li>
                            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Willowvale</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.dropdown-submenu a.test').on("click", function(e){
                    $(this).next('ul').toggle();
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
            });
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```