# Create interlaced Select box

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

Lets assume a hierarchical structure:

```
{ 
  birds: [ chicken, ostrich, sparrow], 
  mammals: [mouse, horse, lion], 
  reptiles: [ crocodile, tortoise, lizard] 
}
```

I want to create a select box, having the categories (in this case: `birds, mammals, reptiles`) as visible options, which appear, when I open the select box. When I hover one of these options, a menu appears on the right side of the option pane, displaying the items that belong to the respective category. When I hover 'birds', I want a side menu that displays the options `chicken, ostrich, sparrow`. Hovering the side menu, it allows me to select one of these options on click, so that, in the end, the value of the original select box.

Logically, this select box should correspond to a grouped select box (`<optgroup>`), but technically it offers more than a mere grouping of options.

Is something like this already available somewhere? And how could I overcome the main obstacles, i.e. option elements not triggering `hover`events?

Comment: The best solution I found is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52525943/dropdown-submenu-in-selection-list/52538162#52538162

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using checkbox as toggle ?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pz3gthrm/)

```
<div class="listitem">
   <label for="type1">
     Birds
   </label>
   <input id="type1" type="checkbox" />
   <div class="listitem-group">
       <button>Chicken</button>
       <button>Ostrich</button>
       <button>Sparrow</button>
   </div>
</div>
```